# Unity 3D Camera wont turn horizontally after adding empty animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I made an Empty child that contains my whole Character. Including the Body and the Maincamera. I want him to do a simple animation. I cant move the camera out of the child because it has to follow the animation as well. When I add an animation, I cant move the Camera horizontally anymore.

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the animation is setting a position in worldspace and overwriting what your script is trying to do, are you sure you have the animation set up correctly